# Bluetooth in Android to connect with arduino

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to get two values from arduino board via Bluetooth in my android application. The arduino board is already paired to my device. How can i receive those values. Anyone ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to write two applications. one on android and the other on Arduino board. you can refer the following tutorial to connect to bluetooth device from android app.

[communicating with bluetooth device from android app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)

Comment: I have my Arduino Code, That send "a" & "b" simultaneously, I want just receiving code, Can u help ?